# Am I doing it right? {{#each}}

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a question because I'm curious if I do it right.
As I'm reading all tutorials about Ember.js every one is typing something like that:

```
{{#each friend in model}}
   {{friend.firstName}} {{friend.lastName}}
{{/each}}
```

And in my app with route for example: `app/templates/works/index.hbs` I have:

```
{{#each}}
   {{#link-to 'works.work'  this.id class="trigger"}}
      <h3 class="title">{{name}}</h3>
      <p class="description">{{description}}</p>
      <img {{bind-attr src=image}}>
   {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

But that still working just fine, so thats just convention or I am doing something wrong all this time?

Comment: Two different flavors of `each`, both widely used. By the way, in Ember 2.0 they plan to merge these, essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with the first form, non-context switching form of {{each}}, as the second form is deprecated. [See here.](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/releases/tag/v1.9.0-beta.3)

The first form is less confusing as you don't need to think of the context for your properties.